# how to put icons menu on single line on android with xml

Tags: android, menu

I created an xml with 3 icons but my problem is how to mange them in wanted place like 3 in one line or more. I am using an xml to build a menu it looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="Date format" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_today" android:orderInCategory="1">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/item3" android:title="hh:mm dd/mm/yyyy"></item>
        <item android:id="@+id/item4" android:title="dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm "></item>
    </menu>
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/item2" android:title="change background color"  android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage" android:orderInCategory="3">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/item5" android:title="white"></item>
        <item android:id="@+id/item6" android:title="black"></item>
    </menu>
</item>
<item android:title="exit" android:id="@+id/exit"
 android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off" android:orderInCategory="1"></item>

</menu>
```

thanks for help!

Comment: have resolved this question? if yes can you explain me how you have resolved? thanks in advance. Marco

Comment: use layout in android,like TableLayout